# VLC player displaying a file with tilde

Tags: vlc

I am using a VLC player for playing music and when I open the music directory in it, it shows all my directories in the music folder on my disk plus one additional file called `song~`. This file is not contained in my directory and I cannot remove it from VLC either. Does anyoen know what is it and how to remove it from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in your directory, it is just a hidden file. If you are using Nautilus: find the folder, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> then simply delete it.

Answer (score -1):

it's not necessary to delete it, it might be a codec for playing songs or hiden file within your folder (probably a hidden file)

Comment: I disagree. While file names ending in `~` are usually not shown in directory listing or included in globbing operations, I don't see what it could have to do with a codec.